# Join List Elements Separated by Dynamic String in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to join the elements of a list and I want them separated by a dynamic string. An example will explain better:

```
import random

foodList = ['apples', 'pears' , 'strawberries' , 'nuts']

quantityList = ["1", "7", "20", "67"]

myJoinedFoods = '<li>' + random.choice(quantityList) + '</li>'.join(foodList)

print myJoinedFoods
```

This prints `<li>1apples</li>pears</li>strawberries</li>nuts` but I was expecting:

```
apples<li>7</li>pears<li>20</li>strawberries<li>67</li>nuts<li>7</li>
```

I'm expecting that every joined item from my list will be separated by the dynamic string `'<li>' + random.choice(quantityList) + '</li>'` as it would happend if I have used a simple/static string like **myCustomSeparator**

```
myJoinedFoods = '<li>55</li>'.join(foodList)
```

This would print:

```
apples<li>55</li>pears<li>55</li>strawberries<li>55</li>nuts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two operations to do:

1 - Pick a random quantity from `quantityList`

2 - Pick a food from `foodList`

Both requires different values each time the expression is evaluated, so you need to separate their processes, as for example:

```
>>> import random
>>> def pick_quatiy(l):
        return '<li>' + random.choice(l) + '</li>'
>>>
>>> s = ''
>>> for f in foodList:
        s += f + pick_quatiy(quantityList)


>>> s
'apples<li>67</li>pears<li>1</li>strawberries<li>20</li>nuts<li>7</li>'
```

Because if you keep the `random.choice` method in your `join` method, it will be evaluated once and then used for `join`ing your list, as follows:

```
>>> pick_quatiy(quantityList).join(foodList)
'apples<li>20</li>pears<li>20</li>strawberries<li>20</li>nuts'
```

Comment: All 3 solutions work and I guess it's a hard job for me to choose the best answer. I've chosen this one because it was displayed first and Iron Fist had the highest reputation score but I also thank waterboy5281 and Ankur Jyoti Phukan for their support. Why not thank Jan for his try also :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension in combination with a function:

```
import random

foodList = ['apples', 'pears' , 'strawberries' , 'nuts']
quantityList = ["1", "7", "20", "67"]


def combine(value):
    return '{}<li>{}</li>'.format(value, random.choice(quantityList))

myJoinedFoods = ''.join([combine(item) for item in foodList])
print(myJoinedFoods)
# apples<li>20</li>pears<li>1</li>strawberries<li>1</li>nuts<li>20</li>
```

Or, even shorter with a one-liner:

```
joinedFoods = ''.join(map(lambda x: '{}<li>{}</li>'.format(x, random.choice(quantityList)), foodList))
print(joinedFoods)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the simple way:

```
import random

foodList = ['apples', 'pears' , 'strawberries' , 'nuts']
quantityList = ["1", "7", "20", "67"]
myJoinedFoods=''
for i in foodList:
  myJoinedFoods+=i+'<li>'+random.choice(quantityList)+'</li>'
print myJoinedFoods
```

Another Way is by formatting :

```
import random
foodList = ['apples', 'pears' , 'strawberries' , 'nuts']
quantityList = ["1", "7", "20", "67"]
myJoinedFoods=''
for i in foodList:
  myJoinedFoods+='{}<li>{}</li>'.format(food,random.choice(quantityList))
print myJoinedFoods
```

Which will give the required output :
`apples<li>7</li>pears<li>20</li>strawberries<li>67</li>nuts<li>7</li>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need as separator, so much as an addendum to each item in the `foodList`. This can be achieved using `str.join()` to concatenate the items in `foodList` + the return value of a `separator()` method.

```
import random

foodList = ['apples', 'pears' , 'strawberries' , 'nuts']

quantityList = ["1", "7", "20", "67"]

def separator():
    return "<li>{}</li>".format(random.choice(quantityList))

''.join(x+separator() for x in foodList)
# apples<li>67</li>pears<li>1</li>strawberries<li>7</li>nuts<li>20</li>
```